# How to access data extensions through rest/soap API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

In our application we allow users to navigate to + select a Data Extension (including in a folder) and then we read the column names from it to help them map their data.  This was originally implemented through the Soap API.  As we have other functions which related to classic email we used to use that, we've since migrated the email functions to use Content Builder.  More recently still we updated to use the new style of authentication tokens + endpoints.

So I had been able to access Data Extensions through the Soap api in the past, but with recent changes to the authentication endpoints this is no longer possible.  My options are to

- Update my authentication code to use new style credentials with the SOAP api
- Update my code to use the REST API to access data extensions

I've had a quick look at the developer docs and it's not immediately clear if either of these approaches are possible.  Does anyone know if data extensions are accessible through the REST api (this is preferable to having a mixture of REST and soap calls, and I'm using REST for Content Builder). Otherwise can I use the new authentication endpoints with SOAP?

Comment: What kind of access are you looking for in regards to DEs? There are a few undocumented REST endpoints that can target DEs, but they are not as comprehensive as the SOAP ones

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would help to know what you're trying to accomplish, please edit your question.

Comment: The answer to this question is somewhat opinion-based. Authentication aside, it's not clear what is the scope of your would-be rewrite from SOAP to REST so it's hard to say whether it's 1) possible 2) a good idea. It seems that updating auth code to use oAuth with SOAP is the easiest way to go.

Comment: I'm after a list of the DE's in a SFMC account, and then I want to get data from each of them.  I'd prefer to use the REST api for everything, but as far as I can see it's not possible to get a list of data extensions through the REST api, is that correct?

Comment: You would need to use SOAP or WSProxy to get the list of DEs. REST does not currently have this capability. See my blog post here for a good starting point on what you are looking to do: https://gortonington.com/data-extension-inventory-for-your-sfmc-business-unit/